# Thread does not stopped using flag as volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

In following code i am trying to start and stop the server on button using java applet.Start works good using thread but i want to stop the server on button. I have used **volatile** variable.Still i am not getting the server stop..

here is code:

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread {
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8002;
    private boolean running = false;
    public volatile boolean stop = false;
    public Socket client = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerBoard frame = new ServerBoard();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        super.run();
        running = true;
        try {
            System.out.println("Server Has Started........ \n Waiting for client........");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            try {
                while (!stop && running) {
                    client = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Connection Accepted......");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    String usercmnd = in.readLine();
                    if (usercmnd != null) {
                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = runtime.exec(usercmnd);
                    }
                }
                if (stop) {
                    serverSocket.close();
                    client.close();
                    System.out.println("Server Has Stopped");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void requestStop() {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

But whenever i click the stop button which will stop the server.Its not showing any output on console as i expected by the code.Its also not showing any error 
here is code of stop button

```
stopServer = new JButton("Stop");
stopServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stopServer.setEnabled(false);
        startServer.setEnabled(true);
        mServer = new TCPServer();
        mServer.requestStop();

    }
});
```

Comment: I'd guess it doesn't stop because `serverSocket.accept()` is blocking. Try closing `serverSocket` in `requestStop`.

Comment: What's the difference between `stop` and `running`?

Comment: @AndyTurner its showing SocketException: socket closed,

Comment: so catch the `SocketException`.

Comment: yup got the output as i expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't stop because you create a new instance before stopping it and you don't even start it first while you are supposed to call `requestStop()` on your current instance of `TCPServer`.

```
// Here you create a new instance instead of using the existing one
mServer = new TCPServer();
mServer.requestStop();
```

Comment: `public void requestStop(){
  stop = true;
  System.out.println("Server Has Stopped"); 
  System.exit(0);  
 }` i have used this too.which gets the output as i am expecting

Answer (score 0):

in your ActionListener implementation for the stop button, you are accessing a different instance of TCPServer (as you are creating a new one). So you set the value "Stop" to a second object. It has no impact on the first instance that was created with the start button.

Try to instanciate the TCServer outside of your implementation of the action listener for both buttons and use that single instance for both.

Answer (score 0):

Due to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

`ServerSocket::accept` is a blocking method, so `stop` variable can only be checked between successful connections.

You can either set a `ServerSocket` timeout using `ServerSocket::setSoTimeout` (and catch `SocketTimeoutException`), or `interrupt` Server thread and catch `InterruptedException`.

Both exceptions will be throwed from `ServerSocket::accept`.

Note, that thread interruption is highly preferred over timeouts and repeatly exception catching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void requestStop() {
    stop = true;
    interrupt();
}
```

However, in this case, we can not guarantee, that already processing logic will successfully shutdown.

Also, you try invoke requestStop for new instance of TCPServer, instead already existing.

Answer (score 0):

your code `client = serverSocket.accept();` is blocking. So once you clicked "stopServer" button, you requested the stop, but it will be acted upon only once a client sends a next request to the server. What you need to do is to run your logic in your method run() in a separate thread and catch there InterruptedException  and ClosedByInterruptException and clean up and return there. On your stopButton click you will invoke interrupt() method on your Thread. Read about it in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--)